# Modify a code to sum two lists (element-wise)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to sum two lists (element-wise). I have the following example:

```
from operator import add

L1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
L2 = [[10,20,30], [40,50,60], [70,80,90]]
W = map(add, L1, L2)
print (W)
```

But the results are:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30], [4, 5, 6, 40, 50, 60], [7, 8, 9, 70, 80, 90]]
```

I want to `sum` elements (for instance 1+10=20, 2+20=20, ...etc). Can this code be modified to achieve what I want?

Comment: You are adding lists, what you need to do is add elements of the list :)

Comment: Do you want a solution that works for any dimension of `lists`?

Comment: @JoeIddon Yes. As long as it is for list not numpy

Comment: `1+10=20`? What?

Answer (score 3):

Using `zip` and `map` with `list comprehension` :

```
>>> temp = zip(L1, L2)
# >>> list(temp)
# => [([1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30]), ([4, 5, 6], [40, 50, 60]), ([7, 8, 9], [70, 80, 90])]

>>> [list(map(sum, zip(x,y))) for x,y in temp]
=> [[11, 22, 33], [44, 55, 66], [77, 88, 99]]
```

***NOTE :*** using just `zip(L1, L2)` is better than doing `list(zip(L1, L2))` as the former returns a `Generator` which is more efficient and faster than building a list.

Comment: Ahhhhh. Haven't thought about that. Thank you very much

Comment: Note: This doesn't work for any number of embedded `lists` though.

Comment: @JoeIddon : could you pls elaborate on what you mean by an embedded list?

Comment: @KaushikNP like a 3-D array or more generally a N-D array where N > 2.

Comment: @ArthurSpoon Yes exactly, I have a more complicated example in my answer where the `list` is nor "rectangular" (as it would be called in `numpy`)

Comment: Hmmm. Ofcourse its not meant for a Multi-dimensioned list. Never had it in mind when writing the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
L1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
L2 = [[10,20,30], [40,50,60], [70,80,90]]
final_list = [[c+d for c, d in zip(a, b)] for a, b in zip(L1, L2)]
```

Output:

```
[[11, 22, 33], [44, 55, 66], [77, 88, 99]]
```

Comment: Note: This doesn't work for any number of embedded `lists` though.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because when you `add` two lists together, you are actually using a concatenation...

Unless you have a good reason not to use `numpy`, this would be easily done:

```
import numpy as np

L1 = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
L2 = np.array([[10,20,30], [40,50,60], [70,80,90]])
W = L1 + L2
```

Or, without using `numpy`, and in my opinion a bit clearer than using `zip`:

```
W = [list(map(add,L1[i],L2[i])) for i in range(len(L1))]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I want to use lists not numpy.

Comment: Updated to add a non-`numpy` solution. Any reason why you do want to use `numpy`?

Comment: @ArthurSpoon `numpy` requires compiled code and is not native to Python so not all Python installs have it...

Comment: @JoeIddon but `numpy` can be easily installed via `pip`, a software manager, probably other things...

Comment: @ArthurSpoon I know, I heavily use it myself, but some people won't be able to use `pip` as it requires terminal / command prompt access which is often restricted at institutions.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pretty neat (even if I do say so myself) *recursive* solution:

```
def add(l1, l2):
    return [add(l1[i], l2[i]) if type(l1[i]) == list else l1[i] + l2[i] for i in range(len(l1))]
```

which, when running with `add(L1, L2)` gives:

```
[[11, 22, 33], [44, 55, 66], [77, 88, 99]]
```

---

The cool thing about this function is that it will work no matter how the `lists` are embedded even if there is a mixture (i.e. not rectangular).

So here is a good example of that functionality:

```
>>> add([1, [2, 3, [4, 5]], 6], [7, [3, 4, [2, 4]], 1])
[8, [5, 7, [6, 9]], 7]
```